# How do I align a label and a textarea?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

My code ends up like:

```
             XXXXX
             XXXXX
Description: XXXXX
```

I want:

```
             XXXXX
Description: XXXXX
             XXXXX
```

"Description" sometimes spans multiple lines.

Code:

```html
<p class="DataForm">
    <label>Blah blah blah Description:</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBlahblahblahDescription"
                 runat="server"
                 TextMode="MultiLine"
                 Rows="8"
                 Columns="50"></asp:TextBox><br/>
</p>
```

CSS:

```css
.DataForm {
}
.DataForm label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: small;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 5%;
    min-width: 60px;
}
.DataForm input {
    margin-right: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 21%;
    min-width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the Description label in the middle?

Comment: Are you using tables or is it inline, are you floating the label left, etc? Can you post your HTML and CSS so we know what your code looks like? It's hard to recommend styles and layouts that might not fit in your code.

Comment: Yep, the description label needs to be centered vertically if possible. . . . I will attach my code

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You need to put them both in some container element and then apply the alignment via the container element.

For example:

```css
.formfield {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="formfield">
  <label for="textarea">Label for textarea</label>
  <textarea id="textarea" rows="5">Textarea</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried putting that as an inline style on my p tag, but it didnt work

Comment: In your case, apply it on `.DataForm * {}`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be inherited? I tried it anyway, but it did not work :(

Comment: My bad, it does work with dataform *, although the way it centers it is kind of odd, it works, so thanks

Comment: The oddness is probably caused by (implicit) top/bottom margins/paddings. Set those of both label and textarea equal to get a "perfect" center.

Comment: A better solution would just be to put `vertical-align: middle;` in each of your rules above, `.DataForm label` and `.DataForm textarea`. Using the * selector can sometimes have side effects.

Comment: You may be right, but if one would `vertical-align: middle` something, one would usually rather apply it on the complete block.

Answer (score 27):

Just wrap the textarea with the label and set the textarea style to

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Here is some magic for all textareas on the page:)

```
<style>
    label textarea{
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>

<label>Blah blah blah Description: <textarea>dura bura</textarea></label>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. The selected answer did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

1. Set the `height` of your label to the same `height` as the multiline textbox.
2. Add the cssClass `.alignTop{vertical-align: middle;}` for the label control.

   ```
   <p>
       <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text="Description: " Width="70px" Height="200px" CssClass="alignTop"></asp:Label>
       <asp:Textbox id="DescriptionTextbox" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="200px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:Textbox>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="DescriptionRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
       ControlToValidate="DescriptionTextbox" ErrorMessage="Description is a required field.">    
   </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Align the text area box to the label, not the label to the text area,

```
label {
    width: 180px;
    display: inline-block;
}

textarea{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<label for="myfield">Label text</label><textarea id="myfield" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `vertical-align:middle` in your CSS.

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td style="vertical-align:middle">Description:</td>
       <td><textarea></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm looking for an elegant solution without tables if possible.

Comment: You should write stuff like that in your question.

Comment: Who is using tables for forms nowadays?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was obvious :(

Comment: I use the following html for parts of a form: `<p><label>Description:<br><textarea></textarea></label></p>`. This way, when you click the `label` element it will focus the `textarea` element. It's not optimal yet, but I'm getting some nice results with this.

Comment: Cool, I wanted to keep the text areas on the same line ;)

Comment: Tables are perfectly valid for forms. It *is* tabular data, albeit with only one data row (or column).

Comment: @Peter Stuifzand, out of curiosity, is there a reason you've opted to use `<p>` to contain the label/description pairs, rather than -just for example- `<li>`s contained in a list?

Comment: The biggest reason that I use `<p>` is that it without styling already shows the way I want it. With `<li>` (and other) I need to have extra styling.

Comment: downvote for tables... We should be getting away from them, and I don't want little nublets to see answers like this. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
textarea { vertical-align: top; }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a height on your td elements.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

means the element the style is applied to will be aligned within the parent element. The height of the td may be only as high as the text inside.