# Textarea label that I can't get to align top or middle

Tags: html, css

check out [this](http://www.rsadler.com/hadiaris/home.html) and if you click on one of the inputs at the top some jquery will happen.
Now you can see my issue, which is the text "Message:" should be aligned with the top of the textarea to its right.

Thanks!!

Comment: There are many question and answers on vertical alignment of text. Such as this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839403/how-do-i-align-a-label-and-a-textarea?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of css applied to the textarea works:

**CSS**

```css
vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: try that with inspect element, it doesn't work for me, what tag did you put that on?