# Align label and textbox using css on horizontal center

Tags: html, css

How can i align the label text in the middle of the div ?

what i'm seeking is something like

```
       -----------
Name: |  textbox  |
       -----------
```

Demo code:
http://jsfiddle.net/53ALd/2053/

Comment: look at this post:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839403/how-do-i-align-a-label-and-a-textarea][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839403/how-do-i-align-a-label-and-a-textarea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```css
label, textarea {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you. Change the markup:

HTML:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label for='name'>Name:</label></td>
    <td><textarea type='text' id='name'></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```css
td {
  border-right: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
  border-top: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
  border-left: 0px solid #F1F1F1;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/53ALd/2059/)**