# Multiple lines of description next to textarea

Tags: html

I want this:

```
textarea
textarea  description line 1
textarea  description line 2
textarea  description line 3
textarea
```

Instead I get this:

```
textarea  description line 1
textarea  
textarea  
textarea  
textarea
description line 2
description line 3
```

I basically copied this:
[How do I align a label and a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839403/how-do-i-align-a-label-and-a-textarea)
still no help

this is my code:

```
<p class="formfield" style="vertical-align: middle;">
<textarea name="vals" id="vals" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
<label for="vals" >
Enter Values <br> Format:<br> GPR,GPR,GPR or <br> GPR GPR GPR</label></p>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just float the `<textarea>`.

```
textarea{
    float:left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4X7y3/)

Comment: I would like the whole element to stay centered horizontally if possible.  When I float the textarea left and wrap it inside a centered div, it goes back to putting most of the description beneath.

Comment: @MatthewClarkson please provide the actual code you're trying to fix to get an accurate solution. The above works according to the code you've provided, there's no centered div in it...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your style of coding you could change to

```
<p class="formfield" style="vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 10px; float: left;">
<textarea name="vals" id="vals" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea></p>
<div style="vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid black;">    
<p><label for="vals">
    Enter Values <br/>
    Format:<br/>
    GPR,GPR,GPR or<br/>
    GPR GPR GPR</label>
</p>
</div>
```

How important is it that description is vertically centered with the textarea?

Comment: Not very important to keep it vertically centered