# How to move the text in the html align to top?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

When I create the text in the html page , I add a multiple line textbox on right side, and it shows like this.

[image]

what I expect is the second picture, what kind of html code/css can achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Please create a fiddle to help people answer your question.

Comment: may i know what is fiddle?

Comment: @RyanChong: It's a site where you can make HTML/JavaScript demos: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @RyanChong: Basically, we're asking you to post your HTML/CSS code along with the screenshots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I align a label and a textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839403/how-do-i-align-a-label-and-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.formfield * {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p class="formfield">
    <label for="textarea">Label for textarea</label>
    <textarea id="textarea" rows="500">Textarea</textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct, the key is lie on vertical-align: top;